# EF Query - SQL "IN" - Same Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I need to get a list of `Users` whom have a relationship with an `Organization`, but only if the current user has a relationship with the same `Organization`.

In other words, if the current user does not have a relationship with the Organization in question, no results are returned.  If there is a relationship, results returned.  This is the query I have right now, but it is only retrieving one user being the current user.

The query below will obviously get all Active `UserOrganization` records where the `OrganizationId` matches the value passed in to the query.  So my question is, how do I know take my current user (`UserId`) and make sure that they exist within this result set before returning records they should not be able to see?

```
var dbUsers = db.UserOrganizations
                    .Where(u => u.OrganizationId == organizationId)
                    .WhereIf(active, u => u.IsActive)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dbUsers = db.Organizations
                    .Where(o => o.OrganizationId == organizationId
                     && o.Users.Any(u=>u.UserId == currentUserId && u.IsActive))
                    .SelectMany(o=>o.Users)
```

If you can't see the `Users` through an `Organization` you can do something like this:

```
var dbUsers = db.Organizations
                    .Where(o => o.OrganizationId == organizationId
&& o.UserOrganizations.Any(u=>u.User.UserId == currentUserId && u.User.IsActive))
                    .SelectMany(o=>o.UserOrganizations)
                    .Select(uo=>uo.User)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is just to check if the current user has  that relationship and decide if you want to continue or not. This saves having to do a potentially expensive database operation:

```
var hasRelationship = db.UserOrganisations.Any(uo => 
                          uo.UserId == currentUserId && 
                          uo.OrganizationId == organizationId);

if(hasRelationship) 
{
    //Interesting stuff here
}
else 
{
    //No access
}
```